# Uploading WordPress theme manually fails upload

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

is it necessary to unZip all sub-folders in Theme folder ?
actually when i download some theme its in Zip format and when i try to upload it it doesn't . 
but when i open the zip file and find more sub-zip folders in theme folder .
for example plugins are in zip format in theme folder.
it sometimes installs and sometimes again fails .

so please help me whats the problem .
is it necessary to unzip each and every sub-folder or plugin in main Theme Zip ?

Comment: I think it's a package of multiple things (theme, documentation, artwork, etc.), so you need to extract and upload just the theme zip file.

Comment: but it dosen't work...

Comment: be sure inside the zip file there's just a folder (usually named after the theme) that contains the theme files. if the zip contains the theme files NOT inside a folder then it's wrong.

Comment: Try asking at super user. This is about software use, not software programming.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Packaged themes come with multiple zip inside, you can extract that theme and if you have good knowledge of wordpress directory structure you can find theme folder only containing theme files like single.php, style.css etc and upload it to theme directory of wordpress and plugins to plugin directory.

Also you can refer to readme.txt come up with in zip which shows how to use and install theme.